# Django Tastypie UnsupportedFormat when call Resource.obj_create from view

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a Tastypie REST API, and need to call obj_create on a Tastypie Resource from a view, to handle the Resource hydration, but I get a error.
I don't want to use any data from my client side post, but I want to build the request manually .. how to do so ?

```
def ajax_add_comment(request):

    field_id = request.POST.get("field_id")
    comment = request.POST.get("comment")

    f = FieldResource()
    field_bundle = f.build_bundle(request=request)
    field = f.obj_get(field_bundle, id=field_id)

    fc = FieldCommentResource()
    fieldcomment_bundle = fc.build_bundle(request=request)
    res = fc.obj_create(fieldcomment_bundle, field=field, comment=comment)
```

When I do this, with a ajax post request i get an error..

***UnsupportedFormat at /dashboard/ajax_add_comment
The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and `content_types` on your Serializer.***

and again, I don't want to use the posted data, but want to build the data myself, then, why do I get this error??

Comment: Please show `fc.obj_create` function or better all `FieldCommentResource` class

Comment: Did you set the content type within your ajax request?